# mysql LIMIT query unsure what to do

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I am a quite  confused now using mysql and unable to get things work :( .

I want to do this:

`$qid` has `question_id` and `$subject` has subject name. Database has a list of questions. For example I have `$qid =  16` and `subject = Chemistry`,  now I want to show 10 questions after `question_id = 16` with `subject = Chemist` .

I am unable to figure out how it will be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your question ids are autonumeric, you can set a limit of 10 and then only show questions with an id >16:

```
WHERE question_id > 16
AND subject = 'Chemist'
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks it works! there is another question raised in my mind. How can I using one SQL command get 5 rows greater and 5 rows lesser than the question number??

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of any way to do that in one command.  You'd probably have to run 2 separate commands to get the rows greater and lesser than the question id.